# Variable redeclaration in c in loop and outside loop?

Tags: c, variables, for-loop, redeclaration

When `int i;` statement is declared 2 times in a program it shows errors but where as when `int i;` is written in a for loop that runs two times, it does not show any error.

```
#include<stdio.h>//code 1 showing error
int main()
{
    int i;
    int i;
    return 0;
}
```

```
#include<stdio.h>//code 2 no error
int main()
{
    for(int j=1;j<=2;j++)
        int i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for loop runs it two times right

Comment: The 2nd code is not C. It does not compile. Surprisingly, however, it is valid C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to understand your problem, also called variable's scope, let's see to the following sample program:

```html
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int I = -1;
    for (int I = 0; I < 3; I++) {
        printf("%d\n", I);
    }
    printf("%d\n", I);
    {
        int I = 200;
        printf("%d\n", I);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I declared the variable I three times.

When declared into the loop the result will be the Printing of the following values:

```
0
1
2
```

After the for loop when I print again the I variable now I refer to the variable declared outside the for loop, the first one I declaration so the result will be:

-1

Now if I open a new scope with the curly braces and I declare a new variable with the same name but with a different value I will get:

200

I hope my description about the variable's scope is now clear

Answer (score 0):

It is because the declared variable's scope is only inside the block of code where you have declared her. It is not seen outside that block.

I have seen your code now.It's clear as day that in 1. code you declared two ints with same name which is not allowed and in 2. code you declared two int with different name so it's good.

Comment: You cannot have 2 variables with the same name(that's way the error occurs in the first code).The 2nd code is good because you didn't declared 2 variables with same names (you have declared int j as first and int i as second variable). This is all I can say to you. Clear?

Answer (score -1):

The first `main` attempts to define two variables with equal identifiers. This is obviously forbidden and results in a compilation error.

The second `main` contains a `for`-loop. The `for`-loop **introduces a new scope**, which, if no curly braces are added, only embraces the next statement or definition (i.e., `int i;`).
`i` is allocated and **deallocated** for **every iteration**, so it really exists just once at a time. All `i`s ever defined are in **distinct scopes**. Therefore there is no naming conflict.

---

If you have a variable in *outer scope* (i.e., function scope of `main`) and one in an *inner scope* (i.e., scope of the `for`-loop), the variable from the inner scope **hides** the one from the outer scope, thus rendering the outer-scope variable inaccessible.

The C11 standard says, §6.2.1.4:

> Within the inner scope, the identifier designates the entity **declared
>   in the inner scope**; the entity declared in the outer scope is **hidden
>   (and not visible)** within the inner scope.